# When i deploy with firebase, some parts of the site work but others do not

Tags: html, css, firebase

For some reason if you go to the page below, the div box does not expand enough to hold the text even after I deployed it several times using Firebase. I think it is a problem with firebase, because when I open the file on my local device it is normal. But when I deploy it has problems.

Can Someone help me find a solution please?

Here is the HTML code

```
<body background="img's/body.bg.jpg">
<header>
    <nav>
        <img src="img's/ae-emblem.png" width="100" height="100" style="margin-top: 30px; margin-left: 20px;">
        <img src="img's/imgbreaker.png" height="113" style="position: relative; top: 10px; bottom: 30px;">
        <img src="img's/adp_logo_en.png" width="272" height="109" style="margin-left: 20px;">
    </nav>


</header>

<main>
    <div class="emcons">
        <h3 class="title1">Emergency Contact Numbers:</h3>
        <div class="enums1">    
            <p>Police: 999</p>
            <p>Ambulance Service: 998</p>
            <p>Fire Department / Civil Defence: 997</p>
            <p>Electric Utility Service(For Electrical Failures): 991</p>
            <p>Water Utility Service(For Water Failures): 922</p>
        </div>
    </div>

</main>
```

And here is the CSS code:

```
.txt1{
font-size: x-large;
color: yellow;
margin-left: 8px;

}

.txt2{
font-weight: bold;
font-size: large;


}

.emcons{
width: 610px;
height: 310px;
background: #D1342D;
position: relative;
top: 126px;
left: 476px;
bottom: 20px;
border: solid;
border-width: 4px;



}

.divm{
width: 410px;
height: 310px;
background: #D1342D;
position: relative;
top: 126px;
left: 519px;
border: solid;
border-width: 4px;

}

.title1{
color: yellow;
text-align: center;

}

.b1{
position: relative;
left: 112px;
top: 20px;
right: 5px;
background-color: yellow;
border: none;
font-size: 28px;
color: black;
padding: 10px;
width: 200px;
}

.enums1{
position: relative;
left: 20px;
color: yellow;
font-weight: bold;
font-size: x-large;

}
```

The CSS is not Only for this Page

here is the site: https://aegov-alrt29072021.web.app/emergencycontacts.html

Comment: I can't see any errors in console and looks fine to me: http://i.prntscr.com/vDFM-2q4R3SEJvsjbaTgSA.png

Comment: @Dharmaraj: Did you visit the link or used the code

Comment: I visited your website.

Comment: @Dharmaraj: Ok but why is this my view: https://ibb.co/3WDp8TM

Comment: Sounds more like your CSS tbh... the last line goes out of box on my phone.

Comment: @Dharmaraj: It's ok, I appreciate you trying

Comment: Just set the .emcons with min-width and min-height and a little padding inside should solve the problem.

Comment: Is this _related_ to firebase? Seems like a CSS problem.